# DoModal Returns -1 Getlasterror says Invalid handle

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, dialog, windows-ce

I am using a Win32 application ,In this DoModal function returns -1 and GetlastError() returns 6(Invalid handle).I tried Deleting GDI handles to repair the GDI Exhausts,Result Fails.

Additional Information:
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and this application is for Compact 2013.

```
if(!bDeviceOpened)
{     
  bDeviceOpened=OpenDriver();


  if(bDeviceOpened == 0)
  {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Please make sure the driver is up and runnning"));
    return FALSE;
  }

}

//Reading the Driver version
DWORD   nBytesReturned = 0;
    if(!GetOID(OID_RPS_DRIVER_STATS, &stats, sizeof(stats), &nBytesReturned) )
      {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to query the stats"));
      }

m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();

if (nResponse == IDOK)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with OK
}
else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with Cancel
}
```

Why I'm not getting the dialog box?

Comment: can you call "CommDlgExtendedError()"?

Comment: Now CommDlgExtendedError() and GetLastError() Returns 0,Still DoModal is -1

Comment: Do *not* use GetLastError(), it doesn't tell you anything reliable when DoModal() returns -1.  That return code just means that the dialog could not be created, use the debugger to find out why.  Step through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoModal() returns -1 when your resource is not mapped correctly with dialog. If you step into **DoModal()** you will find statement

> // return -1 in case of failure to load the dialog template resource

I would suggest you to call **AfxSetResourceHandle();** function before **DoModal()**.

Comment: @SurendranT try to comment /Reading the Driver version
DWORD   nBytesReturned = 0;
    if(!GetOID(OID_RPS_DRIVER_STATS, &stats, sizeof(stats), &nBytesReturned) )
      {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to query the stats"));
      }"